# Outsystems: configuring a connection to access a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection, connection-string, outsystems

I'm using Outsystems Service Studio to develop a web application. I need to configure a connection to access a local server database. I get "Connection String test failed: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." I just figured out I can't connect using "localhost", because the Outsystems server is not local, but I'm not able to find a solution. what is wrong? Other details:

- MySQL Server is up and running
- I selected MySQL in DBMS
- Inserted my schema name
- Inserted the username (with all privileges granted)
- Inserted the user password

Tried both basic and advanced configuration. I inserted j"dbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb?user=outsystems2" as connection string parameters and I get "Connection String test failed: Keyword not supported.Parameter name: mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb?user". I know this connection string can't work , but I'm not able to find a functioning one. I've read many guides about this configuration, but no solution was found. Thank you all for your time and help, feel free to ask for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luciano,

Is your OutSystems environment on-premises or in the cloud? Either way, you need to make sure that this server is able to reach - it as connectivity - to your MySQL database server. Using localhost or 127.0.0.1 is pretty much the same thing as this is an address for the machine where the request is running, which is, in this case, the OutSystems server. Do you have the MySQL database on your local machine? This is not a good approach as you will need to have an address that won't change otherwise the connection won't be stable and you'd have to reconfigure it all the time.

Regards

Comment: Hi André Vieira, the MySQL database is on my local machine and the Outsystems application is in the cloud. I konw it's a bad approach, currently I'm looking for a solution, either moving my database in the cloud or integrating with the application; or move my application on a local server. Both ways seem to be difficult, I never tried and I' ve not found any similar case.

Comment: Hi Luciano, 
Did you manage to get it working? Here's a link for MySQL in the cloud that may help you https://cloud.oracle.com/mysql.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the link. Unfortunally I was not able to resolve my problem, however I concluded my project without using an external database. Thank you for your advice